# How do I trace a broken wire outside?

Tags: electrical, outdoor

Recently, something happened to the wire running from my house to a lamp by the driveway. Unfortunately, the person who originally ran the wiring was not exactly the best at writing how these things were laid out, so now I have 10 yards of wire running under my property *somewhere*.

Will the home wire tracing kits ([such as this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0086GE2C2)) be sufficient for determining where the break is? I've heard that they are more for things like electric dog fences (placed within 6 inches of the surface) and are not quite so effective with electric wires which are supposed to be placed 2'+ deep.

(I also have a break in a wire behind one of my walls, would the same product be sufficient there?)

Comment: Can't say if your linked item would work, but I'd think that if you bought it (preferably at a brick/mortar shop) and found it to be "not fit for purpose", then you could return it. (Keep it immaculate/ keep your receipt, of course.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yea, the closest I've found for a brick and mortar alternative was 5 times more expensive! Granted, it detected wires *and* pipes...